# Javascript Number Function

Tags: javascript, numbers, number-formatting

This is my javascript code. I am not able to print numbers after the decimal point.

```
var num= new Number(6415614361531435.31453143614351351351);
        document.write("Actual Number: "+ num+"</br>");
        document.write("toExponential() : "+ num.toExponential()+"</br>");
        document.write("toFixed() : "+ num.toFixed(5)+"</br>");

document.write("<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>")

var number= 6415614361531435.31453143614351351351;
document.write("Actual Number: "+ number+"</br>");
        document.write("toExponential() : "+ number.toExponential()+"</br>");
        document.write("toFixed() : "+ number.toFixed(5)+"</br>");
```

It is giving me following output.

```
Actual Number: 6415614361531435
toExponential() : 6.415614361531435e+15
toFixed() : 6415614361531435.00000

Actual Number: 6415614361531435
toExponential() : 6.415614361531435e+15
toFixed() : 6415614361531435.00000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That number does not fit within a double-precision float. Accuracy will be lost.

Comment: The significant number of digits in a 64bit  IEEE 754 float is only about 16 (exact value differs from number to number). So your 16 digits before the decimal point are the most Javascript can do for you. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point